# Make Nuxt dev server compile TypeScript files on save?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I'm building a custom server with Express and TypeScript. And anytime I edit any `.ts` file of the server I need to stop the dev server, run `tsc` command manually and run `npm run dev` again. How to make the development server watch and compile `.ts` files (in /api folder) and rebuild everything on save as it works for `.vue` files by default?